# How to get Lookup and Match Column from single source table for tFuzzyMatch in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I am using Talend to do a fuzzy match, I want to do a fuzzy match between two columns of the same table. But tFuzzyMatch will get Match Column from one input and Look up from another input.

What I need is that I want get Match column and lookup from single source.

I am using Talend 5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can perform in-line fuzzy matching by using the tMatchGroup component. This will search for groups of matching/potentially matching records inside the single flow.

The tMatchGroup also allows for the output to be split by match likelihood that is specified by thresholds, giving an output for confident matches, suspect matches and rows that are unique.

The tMatchGroup component also has a graphical wizard showing expected match groups from a sample taken from the input data which can be useful when attempting to tweak the matching algorithms and parameters.

For example, a very basic job using the tMatchGroup component may look like this:

[image: Job layout]

Where the tMatchGroup is configured so that a match group must have an exact age but will apply Jaro-Winkler to the name columns:

[image: tMatchGroup configuration]

You can see in the above screenshot that the tMatchGroup has a match group containing 2 records, one with the name "Tom" and the other with the name "Thom" and they both have the exact same age.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be achieved by creating a duplicate input source**, one used as the main source while the other used as a lookup, the rest is the same configuration as you would set otherwise.

In the tFuzzyMatch settings, you can compare the two columns within the same input (which is not tricked by using two input components that point to the same source) by choosing the Lookup and Matching Column settings inside the tFuzzyMatch components to point to the two columns you need to compare, one from each source (which logically are from the same source).

Hope it helps.